# Tunneling a license based on smartsniff output?

Tags: windows, ssh, putty, port, ssh-tunnel

I use ssh tunneling through putty in windows 7 to connect windows desktops at work and have been able to use ssh-tunneling for a matlab license in the past as well.

However, now I had a program (Dymola) for which we have a network license at work, which I would like to be able to use when working from a distant.

I thought, maybe if I know on which port this program accesses the license server I might be able to get it working, but I guess my understanding of tunneling falls short.

Could anyone help me out with this?

I think this is the relevant output from smartsniff (I ran this on a machine in the network):

```
Protocol   Local Adress    Remote Adress    Local Port    Remote Port
TCP        10.33.135.1     10.112.72.4      51829         27000
TCP        10.33.135.1     10.112.72.4      51829         49165
```

I would like to use putty to tunnel the license.

Comment: dude, those are local ip addresses tha won't work over the internet. you're going to have to use the router ip and NAT/PAT/port forwarding.

Comment: Off course they are.  
As I said, this ran on a machine on the network  
Maybe I was not clear enough that putty would connect to a linux machine on that same network (that's how I connect remote desktop to a pc on the network now, ssh to the linux machine accessable from the outside, with tunnels set up to the machine I want to login to).

Comment: Go on the machine where the license is, and do netstat -abon (that -b does it - showing process names, and requires you to load cmd with administrative privileges-right click it..runas administrator)  it will show you process name and process id.. that should help you to see what lines are of use to you. You try to see what port the server us running on. Also then try connecting and see that IP of the client computer connecting to the server.. with a process like matlab.exe or whatever.

Comment: i'm not sure how useful ssh is within a lan though.

Comment: Apparently I am not being clear, my apologies. I'll try again to sketch the set-up. There is one machine within the (rather large) network I can log in to from the outside (through ssh), I would like to use this ssh server to access the other PC (10.112.72.4) within the LAN from the outside. I can only access that PC for the license, I can not log into it. I think it's comparable to what' going on [here](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Installation-Licensing/License-over-WAN-via-SSH-tunnel/td-p/1558009), sadly I'm at the moment on a network with ssh blocked, so I' ll have to try it later on...

Comment: well you'll have to use ssh -L.  supposing the computer you can get to is 45.65.32.2 (local ip is not so relevant but say it's 10.112.74.3)  and what you want to ultimately access is 10.112.72.4:9999  then try something like ssh -L 1234:10.112.72.4:9999  45.65.32.2  and connect your software to 127.0.0.1:1234 and it should go ultimately to 10.112.72.4:9999  But obviously you don't want port 9999 so find out what port it is the server uses. do this within the LAN. See what port your software connects to on the server.